# How to disable scrolling and re-enable scrolling on a mobile touch screen device

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, scroll

This is not so much of a question as it is an solution to the question.

It was difficult find a solution until I stumbled across the answer in added by hallodom ([How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)) which was responding to a slightly different problem.

I wanted to explicitly document an answer to the problem.  Other solutions are most welcome and would add to the conversation.

hallodom's solution was:

For **mobile devices**, you'll need to handle the `touchmove` event:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()})
```

And unbind to re-enable scrolling. Tested in iOS6 and Android 2.3.3

```
$('body').unbind('touchmove')
```

I used hallodom's solution by simply attaching them to functions called when an object in my DOM was clicked:

```
    $('body').on('click', 'button', function(e){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
             disable_scroll();
        }else{
             enable_scroll();
        }
    });

    function disable_scroll() {
         $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
    }

    function enable_scroll() {
        $('body').unbind('touchmove');
    }
```

Comment: My answer could help you ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
var scroll = true

$(document).bind('touchmove', function(){
    scroll = false
}).unbind('touchmove', function(){
    scroll = true
})

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('button').is(':checked') && scroll == false) {
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    }
})
```

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't see your changes.  Your example works nicely (although it causes some jumpiness.)  How might you bind this to a checkbox, to turn it on and off, like in the example I show?